# Keep session alive after closing browser - Node.js + client-sessions

Tags: node.js, session, session-cookies

I have the following session manager code set up in node.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
  if (req.session && req.session.id) {
    DB.FindUser(req.session.id, function(err, id) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (id) {
        res.setHeader('X-Seen-You', 'true');
        next();
      }else{
        res.json({code : 100, status : false, msg :"Error in connection database"});
      }      
    });
  } else {    
    DB.AddUser({ sessionId: Helper.GUID(), ip: req.headers.origin}, function(err, id){
      if(id){
        req.session.id = id;
        res.setHeader('X-Seen-You', 'false');
      }
      next();
    });
  }
});
```

First time a request is sent, this creates a new session and saves in DB and sends cookie to client.
Second requests onward, the session is still alive and it finds the id.

But if I close the browser and open again, the cookie is not sent from the client.

How do I ensure that the cookie persists. I don't have much idea about this. I thought the duration was enough to ensure that cookie will remain alive.

```
app.use(sessions({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: Helper.GUID(),
  duration: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //(1 month)
  activeDuration: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //(1 month)
}));
```

Additional Info - 
My Client is from a different domain. I have added CORS functionality:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

And in my angularJS code, added withCredentials:

```
clinetApp.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }
]);
```